# Is it possible to parametrize connection from Excel to SSAS? (MDX query)

Tags: excel, mdx, powerquery

i need a help with parametrization of connection (MDX) from Excel to SSAS (OLAP). I'd like to use a cell as a dynamic parametr for connection of MDX query, because there is a lot of data in data source and excel is practically freezing due to this amount - so i'd like to parametrize connection.

I have found one solution with VBA, however VBA cannot be used due to security issues. So i am trying to get the MDX to use a cell in sheet as a parametr.

```
with 
/*
source facts
*/
    member Amount 
    as 
        ( 
            StrToMember('[Company].[Parent Company ID].&[175]'),
            ([Measures].[Amount LC])
        ),
        Format_string = "currency"

/*
result
*/
    select
        {
            nonempty
                (
                    Amount
                )
        }
    on columns,


    nonempty
        (
            ([Company].[Company Name].members - [Company].[Company Name].[All]) *
            ([Account].[Account Code].members - [Account].[Account Code])
            ,
            Amount
        )
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
            MEMBER_CAPTION
    ON ROWS 

    from  
        [Core]
```

So i'like to find a way how to change `"StrToMember('[Company].[Parent Company ID].&[175]')"` to a cell in a sheet. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you build a regular PivotTable which has Parent Company ID as a filter and which has the appropriate rows and columns to match your MDX query.

Then on the Options tab, in the Tools group, click OLAP tools, and then click Convert to Formulas. When prompted you should convert the filters to formulas. Now edit the Parent Company ID filter value cell’s formula and make it pull the ID from another cell to something like this:

```
=CUBEMEMBER("Your Connection Name", CONCATENATE("[Company].[Parent Company ID].&[",A2,"]"))
```